# Always get 404 error in Slim Framework when omitting index.php in URL

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, slim

I created a test hello world Slim app following instructions [here](http://docs.slimframework.com/pages/getting-started-hello-world/).

When I make this call I get a 404 error:

```
http://my_server/my_app/hello/John
```

In the other hand, when I make this call it works grand as I get a "Hello John" message:

```
http://my_server/my_app/index.php/hello/John
```

But, of course, I don't want index.php in my URLs... What can be wrong?

======= EDIT =======

I forgot creating .htaccess file like this (following Slim Framework documentation, and in same directory as index.php):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Now I get this error:

```
/physical_path_to_my_files/index.php was not found on this server
```

Comment: Do you have a `mod_rewrite` or some other server-technology-related setup going, or is this just... as you suggest?

Comment: For instance: http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Remove_index.php_From_URLs/

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish.  I edited my post: forgot adding .htaccess file and now I get a different error, :-(

Comment: I'll bow out now, I'm not very good at `mod_rewrite`, but I imagine that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Excellent @JaredFarrish, thanks for the edit.  Keep fingers crossed, :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your htaccess file is in your `/my_app` directory, change your rules to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /my_app/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

If it's in your document root, you need to append the path:

```
RewriteRule ^ /my_app/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I set the RewriteBase value as /my_app/ and worked like a charm, +1!

Comment: Thank you!! i couldn't even guessed it. so silly mistake.. :-|

Answer (score 5):

Can also change the  .htaccess to the following:  (I had a similar problem, and this solved it for me):

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Worked a charm! Was having the same issue as the OP and this helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if Jon Lin solution doesn't work, means your .htaccess file not working.
you can verify that my adding a garbage line like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /loop/v1/

This is garbage line

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

this will produce 503 error if .htaccess working fine, else you won't get any error.

if you didn't get any error , change Allow none to Allow all in Directory section of apache conf file or Httpd.conf

Answer (score -1):

This resource explains all we need to configure in order to use slim on Ubuntu (It helped me to solve my 404 issue) :

To summarise, there is **two things to configure :**

1. Activate mod_rewrite `a2enmod rewrite`
2. Modify the Apache
   configuration file (change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`
   for the document root)

Don't forget to restart apache2 after the changes : `service apache2 restart`

[How To Install and Configure Slim Framework on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-slim-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04)